# I am getting the following problem in xampp control panel. Can anyone guide me?

Tags: tomcat, xampp

```
03:01:46  [Tomcat]  Problem detected!
03:01:46  [Tomcat]  Port 8080 in use by "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN\tnslsnr.exe"!
03:01:46  [Tomcat]  Tomcat WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
03:01:46  [Tomcat]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
03:01:46  [Tomcat]  or reconfigure Tomcat and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
03:01:46  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
```

This is what being shown. How to fix this?

I am learning to use php in my university and they asked us to use xampp and I encounter this.

Comment: The C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN\tnslsnr.exe application is listening to 8080. You could do any of the following, change the Tomcat server port to anything other than 8080, e.g. 9090 or stop the exe from Task Manager. Essentially the error says, the port is under use.

Comment: How to change it from 8080 to other port?

Comment: To test, open tomcat/conf/server.xml file, search for 8080 and change it to some other number, e.g. 9090 and restart Tomcat and check